# Embedding third party chat widget using Helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby, react-helmet

I'm trying to embed a [tlk.io](https://tlk.io/) chat widget on my `Gatsby` site since no similar plugins seem to exist. I'm using the `react-helmet` plugin to embed that script, but nothing shows up on my page. My code you can find below.

I think it has to do with the fact that the script relies on this `data-channel` attribute in the div tag, but I have no idea what to do with regards to that.

```html
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const LivePage = () => (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Live" />
      <Helmet>
        <div id="tlkio"
          data-channel="hey"
          style={{width:'auto',
          height:400}}></div>
        <script src="http://tlk.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </Helmet>
    </Layout>
)

export default LivePage
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Gatsby documentation about Helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/), and [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) `<Helmet>` component allows you to insert a few code that will be placed after compilation inside the `<head>` tag.

So, in your code, you need to remove the `<div>` tag and it will work like a charm.

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const LivePage = () => (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Live" />
      <Helmet>
        <script src="https://tlk.io/embed.js" type="text/javascript"/>
      </Helmet>
    </Layout>
)

export default LivePage
```

I've tested in my local machine and it works perfectly as it is shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @sug48 it's fine, you've made an excellent question and everyone has started as a newbie ;). It was just a friendly reminder. If my answer has solved your issue please accept my post, if not, please let me know how can I help or what problems have you faced.

Answer (score 0):

React Helmet is a plugin that adds its children to head tag of your webpage. You cannot add div element to head, but instead inside body of the website. Just put that div somewhere outside Helmet and you should be fine.